# How to build notepad++

Tags: c++, boost, notepad++

When I run

```
BuildBoost.bat --toolset msvc-9.0 your\boost\install\folder
```

it gives the message "boostpath.mak" not found

I'm following these instructions [How To Compile Notepad++ From Source](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Compiling_Notepad%2b%2b#Build_Notepad.2B.2B_v5.8.7_.28win32.2C_Debug.29%3a).

Comment: Obviously i have changed "your\boost\install..." with the actual path.

Comment: Right off the bat, does `boostpath.mak` even exist?

Answer (score 2):

The path to boost must be absolute.

Although it shouldn't be required, I'd also recommend running BuildBoost.bat from the scintilla\boostregex directory within the Notepad++ tree - it was only tested in this scenario - ie. don't supply a path for BuildBoost.bat.

Something like this:

```
D:\code\notepad-plus\scintilla\boostregex> BuildBoost.bat --toolset msvc-9.0 d:\code\boost
```

If you've done all that, and still get the error, it's worth removing the `@ECHO OFF` from the first line of the batch file, and posting the complete output.

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of the buildboost.bat batch file*

Answer (score 1):

I did have the same problem and got the error below :

```
getboostver.mak(15) : fatal error U1052: file 'boostpath.mak' not found
Stop.
******************************
** ERROR building getboostver.exe
```

It seems that spaces in the path name to the notepad++ project folder (`...\Visual Studio 2008\....`) caused the error.

Running `Buildboost.bat` from within the `scintilla\boostregex` didn't solve the problem.

After moving the boost folder and notepad++ project folder to a location without spaces, boost compiled perfectly.